# Executing Command and Getting Output From C With MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I have an MPI C program, and I need to get the output of an executable. The executable does a complicated calculation and outputs the results.

The output of the executable is something like this:

```
0.0225873863659866,0.0000000000000000,0.0000000000000000,
```

whithout a new line character at the end.

To execute and get the output of the command I tried:

```
double vals[3];
char command[256];
sprintf (command, "./a.out");

// Execute the command
FILE *cmd = popen(command, "r");

// Get the command output
char buf[256] = {0x0};
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), cmd) != NULL) {
     // Output is separated with ,
     // separate the string
     char *token = strtok(buf, ",");
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
              // store integral value
              vals[i] = atof(token);
              token = strtok(NULL, ",");
          }
      }

printf("vals = (%g, %g, %g) pid = %d \n", vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], pid);

// Close file
pclose(cmd);
```

In a serial test program, this works great. The problem is that with the MPI program, only PID 0 executes the command, and the rest of the processors don't do it. I also tried having each process call a different executable and different configurations of MPI_BARRIER, but nothing worked.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: From your code I don't see why process zero is the only one executing, but having multiple executions sounds like a bad idea to me anyway. Use `MPI_Bcast` to get the result to the other processes.

Comment: assuming you do `serial | mpirun mpiprogram`, then in your MPI program, only rank 0 `stdin` is "plugged" to the pipe (other ranks read from `/dev/null`). So you should read only on rank `0` and then `MPI_Bcast()` the `vals` array.